# JSF Richfaces Calendar Css override

Tags: css, jsf, richfaces

I display some data-tables on my JSF page, eventually, I got my richfaces calendar to work. but my data-tables CSS overrides the CSS of the calendar so when my popup calendar opens it displays the whole page wide.

JSF 2.2
Java 7
Richfaces 4.3.3

CSS:

```
table {
    empty-cells: show;
    width: 100%;
}
```

If I change the width to example 25% the calendar displays correctly but then my data-tables looks horrible. Any way to keep my data tables at 100% and my calendar and maybe a fixed width?

Answer (score 1):

The CSS selector `table {}` is applied on **all** HTML `<table>` elements. If you want to style only some specific HTML `<table>` elements with CSS, then you should be using a more specific CSS selector.

The `<rich:dataTable>` generates a `<table class="rf-dt">`, so the following selector should do:

```
table.rf-dt {
    ...
}
```

#### See also:

- [CSS3 selector syntax](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#selectors)